# How close can I place two transformers?

Tags: transformer, isolation, interference, magnetics

[image: A typical case transformer]

I need to place two of these transformers in a case. How close am I allowed to place them? Can they touch each other (of course, they will be electrically isolated)? Is their orientation with respect to one another important? What kinds of closest placement types do you suggest?

Comment: What type of transformer are they?

Comment: @LeonHeller It is very same to the one in the picture. What other detail are you asking for?

Comment: @hkBattousai - Looks like an E-I type then. Have you got a link? It matters what type because different types have different field leakage shapes. Also it matters what each one is being used for (power, audio, relative signal strengths, etc) For example, a potential disaster is placing a low level audio input transformer next to a high level output transformer. Placing two transformers passing the same signal/level is not much of an issue though.

Comment: @OliGlaser I don't know its type. I have no datasheet. I am not an expert in transformers. I just go to a local market store, I say the seller "Give me a 2x12V 6VA transformer.", he gives one like in the picture.

Comment: @OliGlaser - now he has confirmed transformer type you 'should' make your comment into an answer. Note that Tony S's comment on touching transformers causing mechanical stresses  has some potential merit.

Answer (score 4):

The importance of the placement varies depending on what each one is being used for (power, audio, relative signal strengths, etc) For example, a potential disaster is placing a low level audio input transformer next to a high level output transformer. A similar issue could be the power transformer next to an audio input (or possibly output) transformer.
Placing two transformers passing the same signal/level near each other is not much of an issue though.

Generally, to minimise coupling the cores should be placed at right angles to each other (flux lines at 90 degrees to each other), and as far away as is practical. You will see this done with input/output/power transformers in many audio amplifiers.
Different transformers have different flux leakage shapes, learning about this is useful. Toroidal are generally the best in this area. Shielding (e.g. [Mu-metal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal)) makes a difference also, though more expensive.
A good way to test for satisfactory placement is to apply a signal to one transformer (with a load on secondary) and measure any coupled signal in the other, whilst moving it around. You may need to use quite a high level "transmit" signal, and a simple amplifier at the "receiver" to make the signal easily measurable.

For power transformers, remember there are also heat and vibration considerations, so solid mounting/damping and ventilation needs to be looked at. I agree with Tony that touching is  not a good idea, so if it can be avoided do so.

Comment: could you post a link about different flux shapes and research how it will affect this situation ?